# PHP date("I") for a future or past date

Tags: php, date

The PHP `date("I")` returns either a 0 or 1 depending on if the current date is in daylight savings. However, i need this exact function to return a 0 or 1 for a specified date and time in the future or past.

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: of course, there is an hour in October when the given time occurs both in standard time and daylight saving, so there is potential ambiguity here. It's a fairly small potential, but it is there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just pass the timestamp of the future date like this:

```
is_daylight_saving = date("I", future_timestamp);
```

See PHP [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) documentation

****** EDIT:******

To properly get the daylight saving information you need to make sure that your default locale is set to a country using daylight saving. The list of countries using daylight savings can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_by_country).

To change the default time zone use [`date_default_timezone()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) as follows:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome'); // Italy uses daylight saving
echo date("I", 1366456706); // will return 1

date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires'); // Argentina doesn't use daylight saving
echo date("I", 1366456706);  // will return 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tomas, but i tried that and it does not work. I got a timestamp of 1366456706 which translates to 20 April 2013 and falls within the daylight savings time. When i get this timestamp converted via a timestamp converter it says GMT +1 which indicates that it is in daylight savings but the date("I") is still returning zero. i tried this: date("I", "1366456706"); but not luck

Comment: future_timestamp is an integer, not a string. Try  date("I", 1366456706);

Comment: thanks Tomas, but still returning 0. if i copy and paste that time stamp on a website that converts timestamps to date and time it says GMT+1. is there maybe any other way to quickly determine weather a timestamp has this GMT+1 status? Thanks

Comment: Perfect. Works perfectly now. Thanks Tomas.