# Issue with date() and Daylight savings

Tags: php, mysql, date, timezone, timezone-offset

I'm having issue syncing date calculation between PHP and MySQL on my server.

Right now, server time is: `Tue Jul 1 12:30:35 EDT 2014` with timezone set to `America/New_York`

Running `SELECT NOW()` in MySQL returns `2014-07-01 12:30:54` which shows MySQL date is same as of server.

However, PHP `date('I')` returns `0` and `date('Y-m-d H:i:s T')` returns `2014-07-01 11:30:35 EST`

any idea what is wrong with PHP here ?

Comment: See this Q&A => http://stackoverflow.com/q/14423348/ - It might help shed some "light" on the subject; *pardon the pun* ;-)

Comment: You're setting DST to on with the date("I") which is subtracting an hour from the actual time currently. Always remember "spring forward, fall back" We set the clocks ahead an hour in the spring and we set them back an hour in the fall.

Comment: thx guys for your replies; setting the is_daylisght_saving = date("I", future_timestamp) is not working considering I'm using date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); to default timezone to EST

Comment: For me, `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); echo date('I');` gives `1` and it's `2014-07-01 12:46:11 EDT`.

Comment: Moved all this to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this Q&A => [PHP date("I") for a future or past date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14423348/) - It might help shed some "light" on the subject; pardon the pun ;-) –  Fred -ii- 17 mins ago

You're setting DST to on with the date("I") which is subtracting an hour from the actual time currently. Always remember "spring forward, fall back" We set the clocks ahead an hour in the spring and we set them back an hour in the fall. –  VikingBlooded 14 mins ago

thx guys for your replies; setting the is_daylisght_saving = date("I", future_timestamp) is not working considering I'm using date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); to default timezone to EST –  Stephane Kouakou 8 mins ago

For me, date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); echo date('I'); gives 1 and it's 2014-07-01 12:46:11 EDT. –  Jack 7 mins ago

yes it works now! thx!!! –  Stephane Kouakou 4 mins ago

MySQL, when you `SELECT NOW()`, honors the present value of the time_zone setting in the server.  In PHP you need to make sure it knows the current time zone setting.